# Layering Canvas elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'm working on a pototype HMTL5 canvas animation that will export to quicktime.

I'm having a dynamically generated background with dynamically masked elements on top of it.

I can get the background to be made, and have it export to the server as a frame by frame animation (png sequence) and then compile the animation using FFMPEG into a quicktime. The concept is working.

However, whenever I try to put the dynamically masked elements on top of the background, the background gets affected by the mask too.

Currently the draw opperation I have goes

1. Draw Background element 1
2. Draw Background element 2
3. Draw Foreground Element Mask
4. Switch to Source-in Mode
5. Draw Foreground element fill
6. Revert to Source-Over Mode

I'm obviously using the source mode wrong, but I'm not sure it is possible to do what I want (have a mask affect the element right under it, but not ones below that).

The easiest solution I can think of would be to just layer 2 canvas objects on top of eachother...however I'm not sure how I could combine the 2 canvases into a single image for the quicktime export.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `context.drawImage` method will accept another canvas as the image source.

So if you want to "flatten" all your canvases into a single canvas:

```
yourMainContext.drawImage(yourOverlayCanvasElement,0,0);
```